# WPF Label FontSize and FontFamily correct in designer, but wrong at runtime

Tags: wpf, rendering, label, styles

I have created a WPF application and set style of the controls using styles. I have a problem on some controls such as Label where I have set `FontSize`, `FontWeight`, `FontFamily` etc. All values are working as expected, except `FontSize` and `FontFamily` don't seem to be working correctly at runtime. (At design time `FontSize` and `FontFamily` seem to change to the value I have set.)

I have tried to capture the Style of each control at runtime and I found that the values of `FontSize` and `FontFamily` are correct (same value as I have set).

Anyone have an idea about or experience with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you specified these values some place else that has a higher priority then your style? (eg local property values or triggers)

a code example could clear things up...

Comment: I try to set the FontSize="20" as local value but it FontSize don't change to 20. (FontSize at runtime is 20)

I have no idea about this issue, and can't find the solution at this time.

* I have run this code on many PC and the result was same, except on notebook. It render on notebook as I expect.

Comment: hmm. What's the difference between your notebook and the other pc's? The only thing I could think of is a different (wpf)theme, but that has a low priority, so that should not influence the values you specify locally. Perhaps you installed newer service packs or anything?

Comment: I have installed all services pack, all of environment is same excepts. It's unpredictable situation that local value must have most priority.